# Does the date filter for a CommCare case export filter forms by last modified date or opened date?

Tags: commcare

While doing a case export in CommCare, is the date filter used to filter cases modified between that date range, or are cases filtered by those that were opened in that date range?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The date filter in the case export is based on *modified date*, not opened on.

[image]

If you also look closely at the subtext it will remind you that it is filtering on when cases were modified.

Note: Confusingly enough, at this time the list of cases in your export however will be sorted by the opened on date.