# What are my options for getting around the 100,000 maximum row limit for case export?

Tags: commcare

My project data doesn't easily lend itself to filters that will bring the row count under 100,000 for case export.
What are my options to get around this issue?

Are there ways download case data without going through the "export case" interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now the best way to get around this is to use filters.

1. Date Range - You can use date ranges to select smaller chunks of data. These dates are based on the last time the case was modified (see [Does the date filter for a CommCare case export filter forms by last modified date or opened date?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103226/does-the-date-filter-for-a-commcare-case-export-filter-forms-by-last-modified-da/103227#103227))
2. Use reporting groups - You can further break down your case data by only downloading cases for a set of users, groups, or organizations. (For example, if your cases are evenly distributed amongst your users, you can put them in two separate groups which will halve the number of rows downloaded).

If all of that still doesn't work for you, and you have technical capacity, you can look into using the [commcare-export tool](http://github.com/dimagi/commcare-export)